# user input strings using vector in java

Tags: java, vector

I'm new to programming and we have this activity which we'll have to input the name and address of the customer using the class vector. I really don't have any idea of this class. I really need your help..thanks

---

```
System.out.print("Name: ");
name = sc.next();
System.out.print("Address: ");
address = sc.next();
```

my code was like this...i don't know how to use Vector in the customer's name & address...i used string at the moment.

So, I really need your help. Tnx

Comment: The assignment specifically asks for the use of Vector?

Comment: no..actually, array must be used here. the fact that it's only limited, vector then must be used.

Answer (score 1):

A `Vector` is a `List`, but it's an old "broken" class that should be avoided. I say "broken", because it was supposed to provide safe concurrent access by taking a `List` and making all methods `synchronized`, but this alone was a naive attempt, because some atomic actions rely on calling *multiple* methods - threads can interleave each other and break the state.

Further, a `List` is a poor choice for saving input, because the *order* of items in the list is undefined - that is, it's simply the order they were added. This would make your data look a bit like this:

- john
- 21 jump st
- etc

But the order must be agreed upon by all code using it - this a "brittle" (easily broken).

Whoever asked you to use a `Vector` has no place teaching programming and should be immediately dismissed.

A better choice would be a `Map`, which is a `Set` of key/value pairs. Using a `Map`, you could save the data like this:

- name --> john
- address --> 21 jump st
- etc

Data is effectively "named", so all code using it knows what each piece of data means.

Answer (score -1):

Simple code for adding:

```
TreeMap<String, String> customer = new TreeMap<String, String>();
customer.put("John Doe", "Addr1");
customer.put("Jane Doe", "Addr2");
```

Then you can obtain names

```
Set<String> names = customer.keySet();
```

or addresses

```
Map.Entry<String, String> addr = (Entry<String, String>) customer.entrySet();
```

Comment: btw, treemap useful when you need to store the order of adding elements. if no, use the HashMap

Comment: if you need to add name AND address, it's bettor you use Map. Vector is List, and List is a more complex Array - this is just a bunch of elements. suppose you will have a Vector: "John", "Add1", "Addr2", "Jane" - where there names or correct addresses? =)